# Can ECC Chipkill be used in non-IBM servers?

Tags: memory, ibm, ecc

Can IBM specific ram, such as `41Y2770` with ECC Chipkill, be used in non-IBM servers?

Comment: Please Note Chipkill Memory and Non-chipkill Memory can not be mixed up since chipkill memory is alike to ECC memory with advanced redundancy facility, in case any chip failure happens or any data bit error cause immediately other chips take over the activity just like RAID in HDD. But same facility is not available in Non-Chipkill Memory.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the opposite is usually true, as I installed HP ram in a DELL just the other day (It was just normal ECC though, not ChipKill/ChipSpare).

However, because that RAM has chipkill, it will only work in motherboards that support ChipKill (the same as regular ECC DIMMs can only work in motherboards that support ECC). I know that there are some Tyan motherboards out there that support Chipkill, not sure about other brands.

Answer (score 0):

When Chipkill was first created by IBM it was an ASIC on the SIMM/DIMM. These days Chipkill is standard as part of the memory controller and no special memory is required..